# Wrapping text around a div (in the middle of the text) using css

Tags: css, html, text, css-float

How can I wrap a text around a div. Leaving the div at the middle of the text body using css?

Sketch:

```
text text text text 
text text text text 
text text text text 
text text text text 
+-------+ text text 
+       + text text 
+  div  + text text 
+       + text text 
+-------+ text text 
text text text text 
text text text text 
text text text text 
text text text text
```

NOTE: From the HTML point of view, the div goes before the text.

```
<div></div> [... text...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers are correct in that you'll need to float the `<div>` (e.g. `div { float: left; margin: 10px 0 10px 10px; }`, however, keep in mind that in order for the `<div>` to appear in the *middle* of you content, it will have be *in the content itself*.

When using a float like this, you have to just remember that you have to insert the `<div>` *right before* the content that you want to wrap around it. So, in this case, have a paragraph of text, insert the `<div>`, then have a couple more paragraphs. When you float the `<div>`, it will appear in the middle of your content.

Comment: +1 totally agreed (**I want it in the middle of the text**). To do that I must cut the text in 2 blocks. Using php is easy but I would like a clean css solution. Cut text is very problematic when contain rich content. Seems that is not possible, right?

Comment: To have a div come before the content altogether, but to have it appear wrapped in the middle of the content, using plain CSS - no, that's not possible. It's just not how page flow works. There might be a way to move the div within the DOM w/ javascript, but that's getting messy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to float your div. For example you could style the div like this:

```
float:left;
margin:10px; //To leave a gap around the div
```

Comment: Something like that, but I don't want physically put the div in the middle of the text. The div goes before the text: `<div>text...`

Comment: I dont think that is possible, the only way i see of doing that is using position absolute, but that will allow the text to go underneath the div

Answer (score 2):

what you need is the `float property`. Try this example below:

```
.youDiv {
float: left;
}
```